Can't perform a stratified sample using spatSample in R Terra
I have a raster of categorical values, and I am trying to perform a stratified sample using spatSample(method = 'stratified'). The raster contains the following information:
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 118, 303, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 0.0002694946, 0.0002694946  (x, y)
extent      : -111.5891, -111.5074, 32.70236, 32.73416  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
source(s)   : memory
varname     : cdl 
name        : focal_modal 
min value   :           1 
max value   :          74 

Running the code with my raster yields the error below:
samp = spatSample(cdlRcl, 50, method = "stratified",  as.points = TRUE)
Error in sample.int(nrow(vv), min(size, nrow(vv)), prob = vv[, 3], replace = FALSE) : 
  length(n) == 1L is not TRUE

To test the problem, I ran the following code from the spatRaster() help documentation, and it worked fine:
rr <- rast(ncol=10, nrow=10, names="stratum")
set.seed(1)
values(rr) <- round(runif(ncell(rr), 1, 3))
x = spatSample(rr, 10, "stratified", as.points = TRUE)

I can't figure out what is different about the raster rr compared to my own raster.
rr
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 10, 10, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 36, 18  (x, y)
extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (CRS84) (OGC:CRS84) 
source(s)   : memory
name        : stratum 
min value   :       1 
max value   :       3 

So unfortunately I can't reproduce the problem. Any thoughts on what causes the error?

I'd guess one of the major differences between your raster and  the spatRaster() example is that your are not dealing with uniformly distributed categories. Probably related - https://github.com/rspatial/terra/issues/1503

welcome to SO. When asking a R question, please include a minimal, self-contained, example that reproduces the problem you are facing. Can you please edit your question? You can create the same raster geometry you are using with rast(nrow=118, ncol=303,  etc) and take it from there

Thank you both! Margusl, you are correct. A class that had a single pixel remained in the raster (I had a line of code to remove it that hadn't worked as I thought it did).
